# Swift Save JSON String in a Loop with NSUserDefaults

Tags: json, swift, xcode6, nsuserdefaults

today i figured out how to create a for in method to get different json value.. but now i can't figure out how to save it to have maybe an Array in NSUserDefaults. This is a part of my code :

```
 if let vehicles = jsonData["vehicles"] as? NSDictionary {
                let vehiclesKeys = vehicles.allKeys
                for key in vehiclesKeys {
                    let vehiclenodb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["\(key)"]! as! NSDictionary)["vechicle_no"]! as! String
                    let modelnodb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["\(key)"]! as! NSDictionary)["model_no"]! as! String
                    let variantdb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["\(key)"]! as! NSDictionary)["variant"]! as! String
                    let colordb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["\(key)"]! as! NSDictionary)["color"]! as! String
                    let datepurchasedb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["\(key)"]! as! NSDictionary)["date_of_purchase"]! as! String
                    let insurancecompanynamedb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["\(key)"]! as! NSDictionary)["insurance_company_name"]! as! String
                    let insuranceexpirydatedb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["\(key)"]! as! NSDictionary)["insurance_expiry_date"]! as! String
                    let fueltypedb = ((jsonData ["vehicles"] as! NSDictionary)["\(key)"]! as! NSDictionary)["fuelType"]! as! String




                    var vehicleno:Void = save.setObject(vehiclenodb, forKey: "VehicleNumberSave")
                    var modelno:Void = save.setObject(modelnodb, forKey: "ModelNumberSave")
                    var variant:Void = save.setObject(variantdb, forKey: "VariantSave")
                    var color:Void = save.setObject(colordb, forKey: "ColorSave")
                    var datepurchase:Void = save.setObject(datepurchasedb, forKey: "DateofPurchaseSave")
                    var insurancecompanyname:Void = save.setObject(insurancecompanynamedb, forKey: "InsuranceCompanySave")
                    var insuranceexpirydate:Void = save.setObject(insuranceexpirydatedb, forKey: "InsuranceExpirySave")
                    var fueltype:Void = save.setObject(fueltypedb, forKey: "FuelTypeSave")

                    save.synchronize()




                }
            }
```

with this code the problem is that it save the last value, i need to save both value so like vehicleno will be like = [1vehicle,2vehicle]
how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make mutable array above for loop for example

```
var answersArray : [String]

 answersArray = ["veh1", "veh2", "veh3", "veh4", "veh5", "veh6", "veh7"]

var arrayno = [String]()
for value in answersArray {
     arrayno.append(value)
     println(arrayno)
}
```

so the last value will be

```
[veh1, veh2, veh3, veh4, veh5, veh6, veh7]
```

and you can store whole array....

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely save the last value because you are updating the same "Key" again and again.

The better option is to take empty dictionary add the objects to it.

Example:

```
var myDict: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
```

When the one loop completes, add the object to dictionary like:

```
myDict.setValue("Vehicle1": [arrData])
```

In "arrData", you can save your vehicle details as

```
var arrData = NSMutableArray()
dict.addObject(vehicleno)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't work.. when i save it in NSUserDefaults, it save only the last string

Comment: @SolhilR.Memon Can you help me please!?

Comment: @Marcoc sure, let me go for it!